# Running a web app when user leaves browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a web app built with Ruby on Rails HTML, CSS and JS. This website has a stopwatch which I would like it to keep running even when the user is not on the website.
For example, the user goes with his phone on the website, starts the stopwatch (which is built with JS) and then leaves the browser, goes on other applications of his phone and then when he goes back he should see how much time has passed since they started the stopwatch.

Also, would it be possible to also keep it running even when they close the browser (not the tab though)?

Comment: Only thing you can do, is to hold timing information in database based on logged user. In this case you will be able to keep tracking without dependancy on client.

Comment: For same device/same browser can look at using localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here.

### Store started at time in cookie

You could store the started_at time in a cookie and then read it and set the timer based on that.

```rb
class TimersController
  def create
    cookies[:started_at] = Time.now
  end

  def show
    cookies[:started_at]
  end
end
```

This is the simplest way of implementing it. Of course, if the user deletes the cookies in the browser or uses a different device the timer will get reset.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

## Store in a database

This is a more complicated but also less error prone solution. You could store the information when the timer was started in a database in the backend.

To associate the timer with the started at you would need to create a record with id or hash in the database.

```rb
class TimersController
  def create
    Timer.create(started_at: Time.now)
  end

  def show
    @timer = Timer.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

The url to show the timer would then something like `timers/1` or `timers/abc` be.

A more sophisticated solution could also fetch the timer by user id but then you need to have user authentication etc. too.

In both solutions you would need to refresh the page with JS when the user comes back to the tab though.

Comment: I have used the second solution, storing the time in a DB and sending it to the JS so the stopwatch is updated. However, in order to see the updated stopwatch I need to refresh the page, do you know if there is an automatic way to see the time or a way to reload the page all the time?

Comment: You could use ActionCable (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) or poll with JS after a time out. The more elegant solution would be to use ActionCable.